# HttpClient and extracting audio from server response

Tags: mp3, httpclient

I am using Apache HttpClient to connect to a server for downloading a .wav file. I am using HTTP POST method in my program.

The server correctly responds with the following header and body:

```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n Content-Disposition: attachment;
> filename=saveme1.mp3\r\n Content-Length: 6264\r\n
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n Content-Type: audio/mp3\r\n
```

How do I now extract the saveme1.mp3 file from the HTTP response?  I am using the following code:

```
       ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
       byte[] data = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler).getBytes();
```

However, I am getting garbage when I am writing the data to a file.

```
FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
        fileoutputstream.write(data[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting MIME attachment that you need to parse first. The BasicResponseHandler just return the response string, but you need the body of the attachment that contains the binary of your .mp3. You would need to do the following steps:

- Understand the MIME format. You could skim the [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) for gaining quick familiarity
- Once you understood, you need to create a MIME Parser. This would basically extract each part of the MIME message especially the body of your attachment. I think there should be something out there that you could reuse. You probably should look [MimeMultipart](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html?is-external=true). The only thing that I am not sure about it is whether it handles "binary" encoding in your message.
- Create your own extension of ResponseHandler that will utilize the MIME Parser that you have in the previous step

Comment: You need to implement your own ResponseHandler that read the response and get the content body. I am guessing someone else should have done this already that you could reuse (though a quick search didn't yield immediate result). I'll expand my answer a bit so you could get the steps necessary

Comment: steps are added. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want download mp3 I Think easiest way is :

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Now you have entity and can call entity.getContent(); This give you you a inputStream , now you can save this stream with every method you want , ofcurse you need mime type and filename to save your file. if you have problem with filename and mime type tell me to add some sample code.